# Looking for a word or phrase that describes the "flattening" or "smoothing" of a learning curve

Tags: expressions, idioms, verbing

A word or phrase that describes the process of making something more easily comprehensible.
(I would actually like to exclude the 'learning curve' idiom)

Examples;
"How might we **make this topic more digestible** for our clients?"
"How might we **flatten the learning curve** of quantum mechanics?"

Comment: People often talk of *minimizing* or *reducing* the learning curve.  But maybe you're just looking for, "How might we make this more intuitive?"

Comment: Note that most of these expressions are meaningless, since the supposed shape of the "curve" is (almost) never defined in the first place.  (And I've always heard it described as a "steep learning curve" or a "shallow learning curve".)

Comment: @HotLicks what do you mean? The second example question I posed I believe clearly implies that the curve is steep

Comment: "Learning curve" apparently comes from manufacturing (in particular, military manufacturing) where the term refers to how the manufacturing process improves over time.  In this sense it could be measured and was often expressed as % of slope.  It was adopted as a metaphor to refer to how difficult it is to, say, learn a new computer language, and in that sense it is poorly defined (though still a useful metaphor).

Comment: @HotLicks Good points and interesting history. If you know of any phrases that describe the process of making something more easily comprehensible please share

Answer (score 4):

A suitable expression would be **to make more accessible**.

> [accessible](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/accessible)
>
> **easy to approach**, reach, enter, speak with, or use.

Alternatively, for a more informal flavor, you can use **idiot-proof**.

> [idiot-proof](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/idiot-proof)
>
> built, organized, written, etc., in such a way as to be **usable by or understandable to any person of average intelligence or skill**: an idiot-proof camera.

This may seem a tad condescending if taken out of context, but your mileage will vary. It is listed as an adjective but I think that it can be used as a verb as well, e.g. "We should idiot-proof the user interface." **Please don't use this term when talking to clients/people you don't want to piss off.**

Comment: I think idiot-proof is a term that can be used among developers but should never be seen by the user.  It's potentially highly insulting.

Comment: @MaxWilliams hmm, that is true. I will edit my post to include a big disclaimer. Do you think it answers the question, though?

Answer (score 2):

"*How do we **simplify** this explanation?"

"How do we explain it more **simply and clearly**?*

**Simplify** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/simplify)

> *(verb, with object)* Make (something) simpler or easier to do or understand
>
> *"The two groups are working in partnership to simplify existing rules and information processes"*
> *"Huge steps were made in simplifying information access, mapping, and transformation."*

Comment: I have edited to flesh out your answer. You should answer with definitions, examples and references next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

*[to put across](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/put-across#put-across__1)*, although I don't hear that used much. *[to lay out](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/lay-out#lay-out__4)*, maybe.

Make something plain? Make it transparent?

Answer (score 0):

I read this topic with much interest, but I came to search for the expression "flatten the learning curve" from an entirely different angle: pupils are entitled to an environment auspicious to follow a learning curve as steep as possible, i.e. to learn efficiently and fast. I want to express the idea that a less auspicious environment tends to flatten that curve, i.e. to make their learning effort less successful. I would be interested to have your comments on whether "flatten the learning curve' can be employed sensibly in this context.

Comment: Please don't post new questions as answers to other questions. The SE format is not suited to having multiple questions in the same thread. You can use the "Ask Question" button on the homepage to create a new question and you can link to this question for context.

Answer (score 0):

**Dumb (something) down**

> To make something less complex, nuanced, or intellectually challenging, typically in order to make the content more appealing or accessible to a wider audience. A noun or pronoun can be used between "dumb" and "down."

*The first film was a real exploration of the human psyche, but they dumbed down the second film into a generic horror film.*

*I think there are ways we can make the story resonate with the audience without dumbing it down.*

[dumb down](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dumb+(something)+down)

[The Free Dictionary]

Answer (score 0):

"How might we **facilitate the learning** of quantum mechanics?"

> **facilitate** (v)
>
> To make easier: help bring about [M-W](https://www.google.com/books/edition/On_the_Learning_of_Chinese/oX0fEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22facilitate%20the%20learning%20of%22&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover)

---

> To **facilitate the learning** of Chinese, it is essential to develop
> a pedagogy and curriculum which are based on the needs of learners and
> subsequently increase their orthographic awareness to distinguish the
> similarities and differences among different characters. [Shek Kam Tse
> and Wai Ming Cheung; "Chinese and the Learning of Chinese" in  F. Marton and S.K. Tse (Eds.) *On the
> Learning of Chinese*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/On_the_Learning_of_Chinese/oX0fEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22facilitate%20the%20learning%20of%22&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

> Among others, Ottesen (2001) and Blomhøj and Kjeldsen (2010) have
> shown how modelling can **facilitate the learning** of tertiary
> mathematics. [M. Niss and W. Blum; *The learning and Teaching of
> Mathematical Modelling, p.135*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Learning_and_Teaching_of_Mathematica/tD73DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22facilitate%20the%20learning%20of%22&pg=PA135&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

> In other words, it is only possible to **facilitate the learning** of
> others if you know how to **facilitate your own**. [Peter Jarvis et
> al.; *The Theory & Practice of Learning*, p.99](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Theory_Practice_of_Learning/TjoIGr8HrdoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22facilitate%20the%20learning%20of%22&pg=PA99&printsec=frontcover) (2003)